# SSL on application in nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, web

I am running an nginx web server where I redirect all http requests to https (with a self signed cert).

Problem is - I cannot seem to do so for an app running on a port. Example:

http://my.server.ip:1234

How can I modify the nginx config file to force that url through ssl?

Answer (score 1):

try this:
return 301 https://my.server.ip:1234$request_uri;